# Was the Oracle restored from a backup?

Tags: the-matrix

In Matrix : Revolutions we clearly see how the Oracle let Smith "infect" her (thereby giving him the 'Eyes of Oracle' as she is acting voluntarily) yet in the end she meets with Sati in a park talking to the Architect.

My questions are; How is she "back" (and why does she have **same** physical appearance despite her shell being destroyed)?

Out-of-universe, I understand that it would cause a lot of confusion and critique to change the actress in last 2 minutes of the movie but I am looking for an in-universe answer.

[image]

Comment: *"...would cause lot of confusion and critique to chnge the actress in last 2 minutes of the movie..."* Only if it isn't explained at all, which could have happened in one or two dialog lines. Also it's pretty much how all new regenerations of the Doctor (Who) are introduced, so I wouldn't consider it to be too far off. As such, I'd consider the decision to keep the acress to be some in-universe reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When Smith takes over the inhabitants of the Matrix (including the Oracle), their [shells](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Oracle) don't seem to have been *destroyed*, merely *temporarily overwritten*.

Once the Mainframe regains access of Smith's program, it forces the Smiths to go all explodey (**kaboom!**) and then restores the Matrix to its pre-Smith settings, wiping the memories of the humans inside the Matrix and repairing the physical damage caused.

This restoration also seems to revive and restore the various **Programs** who were subsumed (Seraph, The Oracle, Sati, etc) to their former status, as you can see from the scene below.

[image]

Comment: so i am going to understand this as what Smith did was not as drastical measure as what Merowinger did. Makes perfect sence as (real world analogy) a modigication in RAM can be detected by an antivirus software and reverted but termination of a program forces it to be restarted creating a new instance. thank you

Comment: You should note that this is a theory. It is not guaranteed that what happens with eg. the 'Smith kaboom' has to do anything with the Mainframe. I think it's a mere interpretation by some fans, and I suggest that you should *not* make it look like canon, except if you can prove otherwise. (For example some group of fans prefer a more spiritual explanation to the same thing, etc. etc.)