# How many times do we see things entirely in code within the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

I can only recall two examples where we see the Matrix entirely in code (or rather, when it shows Neo viewing the Matrix as code, as I believe he's the only one who can do this).

Those two examples are after Neo gets up after being "killed" in the first film, and when we see Seraph's code when Neo first meets him in *The Matrix: Reloaded*.

[image]
[image]

**Those are the only two instances I can think of where we see the Matrix all in code; are there any more?** This isn't just restricted to the films; examples from the Animatrix, video games and official comics are also welcome (basically any official canon source).

---

Note that I'm only interested in instances that occur within the Matrix; so any examples within Construct programs or examples of Neo seeing gold code outside the Matrix in *The Matrix: Revolutions* don't count.

Also, I'm only looking for instances of when you see everything in code, not just partially in code; an example of something that doesn't count is when we see Sati and the cat after the Matrix is reset at the end of *Revolutions*, where we kinda see a bit of green code as the Matrix being is restored, just before the cat goes up to Sati (see the gif in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/56731/85712)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neo sees the Agents as code at the end of *The Matrix*.

Neo sees Seraph as (gold) code in *The Matrix Reloaded*.

We (the audience) see the code-cake and its effects on the lady who eats it, as code in *The Matrix Reloaded*.

We see Trinity as code at the end of *The Matrix Reloaded* when Neo pulls out the bullet.

We see the Oracle as code when Smith assimilates her in *The Matrix Revolutions*

'Code vision' is seen in [several cut-scenes](https://youtu.be/584Q2tJeNHc?t=876) in *The Matrix: Path of Neo*